# TClientSocket and Threads

Tags: multithreading, delphi

Okay guys, I'm using TClientSocket class and Threads to work simultaneously with a list of hosts. It's all good but I started note that after sometime, all threads get stucked into a ReceiveBuf call... If I open 10 threads, to check 100 hosts for example, it will start good, but after sometime all threads will be stucked because for some reason some hosts don't answer fine for this ReceiveBuf call... I tried to do a ReceiveLength and check if receive > 0, to call the ReceiveBuf, but still not working.
I'll post the original code below:

```
function Threads.ReceiveProtocolVersion;
var
   ProtocolVersion: array[0..11] of AnsiChar;
begin
 try
    MySocket.Socket.ReceiveBuf(ProtocolVersion, SizeOf(ProtocolVersion));
    Version:= AnsiString(ProtocolVersion);
   ...//continues but doesn't matter because many threads get stucked in the ReceiveBuf call...
 except
    Terminate; //we terminate thread if raise some exception..
```

Ok, so after some researchs, I started tryin to do like this:

```
function Threads.ReceiveProtocolVersion;
var
   ProtocolVersion: array[0..11] of AnsiChar;
   SizeBuf: integer;
begin
 try
    SizeBuf:= MySocket.Socket.ReceiveLength;
    if SizeBuf > 0 then
     begin
       MySocket.Socket.ReceiveBuf(ProtocolVersion, SizeOf(ProtocolVersion));
       Version:= AnsiString(ProtocolVersion);
        ....
     end;
 except
    Terminate; //we terminate thread if raise some exception..
```

Apparently, it solved the problem about threads getting stucked in ReceiveBuf call, but for some unknown reason, none (not even the ones that was working right) threads get inside the 'if SizeBuf > 0'.
Any help?

//Edit showing more of Thread code::
The Thread.Execute is like this:

```
procedure MyThread.Execute;
begin
  while not(Terminated) do
    begin
      if SocketConnect then
        begin
          if ReceiveProtocolVersion then
           begin
              DoAuthentication;
            end;
         end;
          MySocket.Close;
          MySocket.Free;
    end;
    Terminate;
end;
```

The SocketConnect function is:

```
function MyThread.SocketConnect: bool;
begin
  Result:= false;
  MySocket:= TClientSocket.Create(Nil);
  MySocket.Port:= StrToInt(Form1.Edit1.Text);
  MySocket.ClientType:= ctBlocking;
  MySocket.Host:= Host; //Host is a private variable for thread class
  try
    MySocket.Active:= true;
    if (MySocket.Socket.Connected = true) then
      Result:= true;
  except
    Terminate;
  end;
end;
```

Comment: Where is `MySocket` being initialized? Does each thread have its own `TClientSocket`?  Are you using blocking or non-blocking mode for the socket?  There is not enough code to diagnose your problem.

Comment: MySocket is initialized in another function from thread class... Each thread have it's own TClientSocket. I'm using blocking mode for the socket...

Comment: Can you show more of the thread code to show how exactly the thread is using the `TClientSocket`?

Comment: It's posted... Thank you.

Comment: By the way the first sentence reads, you could be running into what I ran into in trying to write a downloader.  I found that given enough time, the OS takes away attention from the thread and then my download stalls.  If your problem isn't solved, try adding   "ClientSocketThread.Priority := tpTimeCritical;" into your TThread initializations and see if it helps.

Comment: Still not working.. And the interesting thing is that when debugging it works...

Answer (score 1):

I fix the problem using TWinSocketStream. Something like this:

```
function MyThread.CheckProtocol: bool;
var
  SockStream: TWinSocketStream;
  ProtocolVersion: array[0..11] of AnsiChar;
begin
 try
    SockStream := TWinSocketStream.Create(MySocket.Socket, 3000);
    SockStream.Read(ProtocolVersion, SizeOf(ProtocolVersion));
    RFBVer:= AnsiString(ProtocolVersion);
    ....
```

I read that the correct way to work with blocking-mode sockets is by sending/receiving data over TWinSocketStream in:
[DocWiki Embarcadero](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/XE2/en/System.Win.ScktComp.TClientSocket.ClientType)

Anyway, thank for the guys who tried to help!